# apps crash on iphone4

Tags: applications, iphone

I have an iphone4 running the up-to-date version: 7.1.2 since the IOs software is no longer updated for an iphone4. Recently many apps simply crash: such as

- chrome
- google maps
- shazam
- IMDB

I assume that the app version is too high for my iphone4. If this is so, then why do such apps update automatically without first testing whether the hardware can support the newest app version? Are there ways I can stop this in the future?  Finally, can one downgrade the app version to something that works?

Comment: You can see the minimum iOS version required by an app in the app store when you scroll down on the apps App Store page. As a matter of fact, Chrome requires iOS 7, so thats **not** the reason apps crash. You could create a backup and restore the device.

Comment: @Lukas I am restoring the device now...

Comment: Well, that was a lovely two hours...a good old fashioned reboot; the restore has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its supposed that the apps that you can download should work well on your iphone, in the case where the app is not compatible with that iOS version it should pop you an alert, if some app does not work correctly the only thing you can do is:

- What you are doing right now, restore the device and manage well your iphone storage.
- Post an App Store review in which you describe yout problem..

This type of issues are not supposed to happen, especially with big developers like Google but..who knows.